# Vector of random numbers with fixed sampling rate

Tags: sampling

How to create a vector of random numbers(in Matlab), when each value is [0,1] .

And the sampling rate should be fixed ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sampling rate doesn't change anything. Simply call [**rand**](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) function:

```
x = rand(1, N);
```